# Ember.js pushState router takeover Laravel route

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ember.js, laravel, pushstate

I'm developing a Laravel/Ember.js app where Laravel serves a general role of a backend framework and RESTful data supplier and Ember.js partially for the client side.

So far it works fine. However I want Ember.js to take control for some of the sub-urls.

Say I have `/members` route in Laravel which serves Ember app and I want sub-consequent URL to take advantage of pushState w/ Ember like so:

`/members/add`, `/members/edit/1` etc.. instead of `/members#/add`, `/members#/edit/1`

With Ember this is easily achieved:

```
App.Router.reopen({
    location: 'history', //instead of 'hash'
    rootURL: '/members'
})
```

and it works fine when I click on the links.

However, when I refresh the page Laravel router kicks in with `.htaccess` which tries to serve every url through laravel's index.php in public folder. Here's Laravel original `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm no expert in Apache URL rewriting, so what I need to do is tell `.htaccess` to rewrite everything that follows `/members` (`/members/add`, `/members/view` etc..) back to `/members` route so Ember.js would take over and redirect appropriately.

I was trying to do something like this, but it didn't work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   Options -MultiViews
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   IndexIgnore */*
   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /members
   RewriteRule (.*) members

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help on this topic of url rewriting is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: wow. didn't know ember.js makes history push state so easy.... learnt a new thing today. thank you (I know my comment isn't helpful here but just wanted to thank) :)

Comment: Yeah, no worries. It's helpful for single page apps with no other routes behind.

Comment: Were you able to find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 1):

take a look:

[image]

It's working for me!

Bye!